# Trying to Save PDF File to GCS / nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We're attempting to save a PDF file to GCS after receiving a response from API. However, the response we got shows like this

```
%PDF-1.7\n%����\n18 0 obj\n<</Pages 35 0 R/Type/Catalog>>\nendobj\n43 0 obj\n<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 53>>\nstream\nx�*T0�30P0�\u0013P��\u0005�k������k����\u0010��]���!�r#�r@\u0000\u0000\u0000��X�\u0012�\nendstream\nendobj\n39 0 obj\n<</BBox[0.000000000000 0.000000000000 419.039980000000 594.959960000000]/Filter/FlateDecode/Length 4312/Matrix[1.000000000000 ....
```

Even though we succeeded in uploading the file, it won't open.

Our function to upload GCS is like this

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage')

async uploadFileToGCS(id, response) {
    const storage = new Storage();
    const bucket = storage.bucket('<bucket name>');
    const fileSuffix = 'pdf';
    const getBucketFile = fileName => bucket.file(`${fileName}.${fileSuffix}`);

    const upload = data =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const uuid = `${id}`;
        const file = getBucketFile(uuid);
        const stream = file.createWriteStream({
          metadata: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${uuid}.pdf`,
          },
          resumable: false,
        });
        stream.write(new Buffer.from(data, 'binary'));
        stream.on('error', err => {
          reject(err);
        });

        stream.on('finish', () => {
          resolve(uuid);
        });

        stream.end(Buffer.from(data, 'binary'));
      });

    await upload(response);
  },
```

We're hoping to successfully upload and open the file without any problems. Is there any better solution or approach to our problem?

Thank You Very Much.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `contentType` and `contentDisposition` instead of `Content-Type` and `Content-Diposition`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, we still cannot open the file. Is there any missing code or another alternative for this? thank you